# Use "renderer/renderer2" in Angular to get value of DOM input in component

Tags: angular, typescript, renderer

I have started learning Angular recently, I want to take the value from a form and send it to a database [Firebase]. I'm using angularfire2.

According to docs there is "setValue()" method but no "value()" or "getValue()" methods. Is there any other method to use?

-TIA

Comment: what does renderer have to do with this. Also there wouldn't be need for that if you just want a value from an input. Please show your code. No one can help otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a get property called [`value`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#value) in the formgroup API in angular.

you can get the value of the form group using `this.yourFormGroupName.value`.

If you want to get the value of the disabled controls, you can use [`getRawValue()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getRawValue) method. `this.yourFormGroupName.getRawValue()`.

Comment: could you please post the syntax. PS I am not using a form

Comment: Share ur code first, i can show u how to get the value

Comment: You said you are using form and now you don't? Share your code so we can understand what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

Your question and title description are not the same.

> I want to take the value from a form

```
this.form.value
```